# Filtering an array with a function that returns a promise

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Given

```
let arr = [1,2,3];

function filter(num) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if( num === 3 ) {
        res(num);
      } else {
        rej();
      }
    }, 1);
  });
 }

 function filterNums() {
   return Promise.all(arr.filter(filter));
 }

 filterNums().then(results => {
   let l = results.length;
   // length should be 1, but is 3
 });
```

The length is 3 because Promises are returned, not values. Is there a way to filter the array with a function that returns a Promise?

Note: For this example, fs.stat has been replaced with setTimeout, see https://github.com/silenceisgolden/learn-esnext/blob/array-filter-async-function/tutorials/array-filter-with-async-function.js for the specific code.

Comment: *"Is there a way to filter the array with a function that returns a Promise?"* Certainly not with using `Array#filter`.

Comment: @FelixKling That is what I'm concluding as well, but can you explain the why behind this further? I'm not comprehending why this is the case; it does seem semi-logical to me.

Comment: because filter expects a function which returns a boolean, not a promise object

Comment: @JonahWilliams Yes, I understand that. Changing the filter function to an async function produces the same results, so I'm guessing that also returns a promise instead of the await waiting for the returned boolean.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Array.prototype.filter` is **synchronous and therefore does not support Promises.**

Since you can now (theoretically) subclass built-in types with ES6, you should be able to add your own asynchronous method which wraps the existing filter function:

*Note: I've commented out the subclassing, because it's not supported by Babel just yet for Arrays*

```js
class AsyncArray /*extends Array*/ {
  constructor(arr) {
    this.data = arr; // In place of Array subclassing
  }

  filterAsync(predicate) {
     // Take a copy of the array, it might mutate by the time we've finished
    const data = Array.from(this.data);
    // Transform all the elements into an array of promises using the predicate
    // as the promise
    return Promise.all(data.map((element, index) => predicate(element, index, data)))
    // Use the result of the promises to call the underlying sync filter function
      .then(result => {
        return data.filter((element, index) => {
          return result[index];
        });
      });
  }
}
// Create an instance of your subclass instead
let arr = new AsyncArray([1,2,3,4,5]);
// Pass in your own predicate
arr.filterAsync(async (element) => {
  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(element > 3);
    }, 1);
  });
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result)
});
```

[Babel REPL Demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20AsyncArray%20%2F*extends%20Array*%2F%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(arr)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20this.data%20%3D%20arr%3B%20%2F%2F%20In%20place%20of%20Array%20subclassing%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20filterAsync(predicate)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Take%20a%20copy%20of%20the%20array%2C%20it%20might%20mutate%20by%20the%20time%20we've%20finished%0D%0A%20%20%20%20const%20data%20%3D%20Array.from(this.data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Transform%20all%20the%20elements%20into%20an%20array%20of%20promises%20using%20the%20predicate%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20as%20the%20promise%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Promise.all(data.map((element%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20predicate(element%2C%20index%2C%20data)))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Use%20the%20result%20of%20the%20promises%20to%20call%20the%20underlying%20sync%20filter%20function%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20.then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20data.filter((element%2C%20index)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20result%5Bindex%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Create%20an%20instance%20of%20your%20subclass%20instead%0D%0Alet%20arr%20%3D%20new%20AsyncArray(%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Pass%20in%20your%20own%20predicate%0D%0Aarr.filterAsync(async%20(element)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(res%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20setTimeout(()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20res(element%20%3E%203)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%201)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%7D).then(result%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20console.log(result)%0D%0A%7D)%3B)

Comment: This is invalid since `super()` must be called before any assignment to `this` inside `constructor`

Comment: @FarzadYZ The implementation of subclass was just an example. You wouldn't need a constructor with true subclassing, as you would be using the base Array constructor and not using your own data store

Comment: You're right, I was just warning for the folks who blindly copy-paste the accepted answer :)

Comment: @FarzadYZ Ah good point, it does look like you can just uncomment that block and have it work...

Answer (score 90):

Here is a 2017 elegant solution using async/await :

Very straightforward usage:

```
const results = await filter(myArray, async num => {
  await doAsyncStuff()
  return num > 2
})
```

The helper function (copy this into your web page):

```
async function filter(arr, callback) {
  const fail = Symbol()
  return (await Promise.all(arr.map(async item => (await callback(item)) ? item : fail))).filter(i=>i!==fail)
}
```

Demo:

```js
// Async IIFE
(async function() {
  const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  // This is exactly what you'd expect to write 
  const results = await filter(myArray, async num => {
    await doAsyncStuff()
    return num > 2
  })

  console.log(results)
})()


// Arbitrary asynchronous function
function doAsyncStuff() {
  return Promise.resolve()
}


// The helper function
async function filter(arr, callback) {
  const fail = Symbol()
  return (await Promise.all(arr.map(async item => (await callback(item)) ? item : fail))).filter(i=>i!==fail)
}
```

I'll even throw in a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/krabbypattified/pen/qYrNrG?editors=0011).

Comment: This has a subtle difference in behaviour to normal Array.filter: if you try to filter an array in a way that _includes_ undefined elements, you'll lose them. E.g. `filter([1, 2, undefined, 3], (x) => x !== 1)` will return `[2, 3]`, not `[2, undefined, 3]`, as it should.

Comment: @TimPerry correct, feel free to revise the answer so something that makes more sense :)

Comment: One option would be to return a `Symbol` sentinel value instead of `undefined`.

Comment: @Tamlyn added Symbol sentinel to fix `undefined` situation  :)

Comment: Probably this function should be renamed into something different like `filterAsync`. I confess that, in my rash SO-and-paste workflow, have only read the first paragraph of your answer, sawn that you used `filter()`, and assumed `Array.filter` would support asynchronous callbacks ... 

Comment: @Tamlyn so just based on your answer and without yet verifying, I would assume returning Symbols for failed predicates gets rid of the undefined. But do you have any reading on why this is or how you came to know this behavior would work?

Answer (score 37):

For typescript folk (or es6 just remove type syntax)

```
function mapAsync<T, U>(array: T[], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => Promise<U>): Promise<U[]> {
  return Promise.all(array.map(callbackfn));
}

async function filterAsync<T>(array: T[], callbackfn: (value: T, index: number, array: T[]) => Promise<boolean>): Promise<T[]> {
  const filterMap = await mapAsync(array, callbackfn);
  return array.filter((value, index) => filterMap[index]);
}
```

es6

```
function mapAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  return Promise.all(array.map(callbackfn));
}

async function filterAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  const filterMap = await mapAsync(array, callbackfn);
  return array.filter((value, index) => filterMap[index]);
}
```

es5

```
function mapAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  return Promise.all(array.map(callbackfn));
}

function filterAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  return mapAsync(array, callbackfn).then(filterMap => {
    return array.filter((value, index) => filterMap[index]);
  });
}
```

edit: demo

```js
function mapAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  return Promise.all(array.map(callbackfn));
}

function filterAsync(array, callbackfn) {
  return mapAsync(array, callbackfn).then(filterMap => {
    return array.filter((value, index) => filterMap[index]);
  });
}

var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function isThreeAsync(number) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(number === 3);
    }, 1);
  });
}

mapAsync(arr, isThreeAsync).then(result => {
  console.log(result); // [ false, false, true, false ]
});

filterAsync(arr, isThreeAsync).then(result => {
  console.log(result); // [ 3 ]
});
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Only tweak I made was to add `readonly` to the array parameter types.

Comment: Needs a demonstration of how to call it

Answer (score 31):

Here's a way:

```
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var filter = num => wait(1).then(() => num == 3);

var filterAsync = (array, filter) =>
  Promise.all(array.map(entry => filter(entry)))
  .then(bits => array.filter(entry => bits.shift()));

filterAsync([1,2,3], filter)
.then(results => console.log(results.length))
.catch(e => console.error(e));
```

The `filterAsync` function takes an array and a function that must either return `true` or `false` or return a promise that resolves to `true` or `false`, what you asked for (almost, I didn't overload promise rejection because I think that's a bad idea). Let me know if you have any questions about it.

```js
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
var filter = num => wait(1).then(() => num == 3);

var filterAsync = (array, filter) =>
  Promise.all(array.map(entry => filter(entry)))
  .then(bits => array.filter(entry => bits.shift()));

filterAsync([1,2,3], filter)
.then(results => console.log(results.length))
.catch(e => console.error(e));

var console = { log: msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>",
                error: e => console.log(e +", "+ (e.lineNumber-25)) };
```

```html
<div id="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 14):

Promise Reducer to the rescue!

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce((op, n) => {
    return op.then(filteredNs => {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                if (n >= 3) {
                    console.log("Keeping", n);
                    resolve(filteredNs.concat(n))
                } else {
                    console.log("Dropping", n);
                    resolve(filteredNs);
                }
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
}, Promise.resolve([]))
.then(filteredNs => console.log(filteredNs));
```

Reducers are awesome. "Reduce my problem to my goal" seems to be a pretty  good strategy for anything more complex than what the simple tools will solve for you, i.e. filtering an array of things that aren't all available immediately.

Answer (score 7):

asyncFilter method:

```
Array.prototype.asyncFilter = async function(f){
    var array = this;
    var booleans = await Promise.all(array.map(f));
    return array.filter((x,i)=>booleans[i])
}
```

Comment: just wondering, would it work if any of the callback rejects the promise/throws an error ?

Comment: @sktguha if any promise rejects or throws, `asyncFilter` will reject as well.

Answer (score 6):

Two lines, completely typesafe

```
export const asyncFilter = async <T>(list: T[], predicate: (t: T) => Promise<boolean>) => {
  const resolvedPredicates = await Promise.all(list.map(predicate));
  return list.filter((item, idx) => resolvedPredicates[idx]);
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Late to the game but since no one else mentioned it, Bluebird supports Promise.map which is my go-to for filters requiring aysnc processing for the condition,

```
function filterAsync(arr) {
    return Promise.map(arr, num => {
        if (num === 3) return num;
    })
        .filter(num => num !== undefined)
}
```

Comment: great point! Moreover, as of now there is even Promise.filter in Bluebird http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.filter.html

Answer (score 4):

In case someone is interested in modern typescript solution (with fail symbol used for filtering):

```
const failSymbol = Symbol();

export async function filterAsync<T>(
  itemsToFilter: T[],
  filterFunction: (item: T) => Promise<boolean>,
): Promise<T[]> {
  const itemsOrFailFlags = await Promise.all(
    itemsToFilter.map(async (item) => {
      const hasPassed = await filterFunction(item);

      return hasPassed ? item : failSymbol;
    }),
  );

  return itemsOrFailFlags.filter(
    (itemOrFailFlag) => itemOrFailFlag !== failSymbol,
  ) as T[];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For production purposes you probably want to use a lib like [lodasync](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodasync#filterasynccallback-collection):

```js
import { filterAsync } from 'lodasync'

const result = await filterAsync(async(element) => {
  await doSomething()
  return element > 3
}, array)
```

Under the hood, it maps your array by invoking the callback on each element and filters the array using the result. But you should not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

There is a one liner to to do that.

```
const filterPromise = (values, fn) => 
    Promise.all(values.map(fn)).then(booleans => values.filter((_, i) => booleans[i]));
```

Pass the array into `values` and the function into `fn`.

More description on how this one liner works is available [here](https://dev.to/praveenkumarrr/filtering-an-array-using-a-function-that-returns-a-promise-3aa).

Comment: This is rather beautiful.  I needed to filter an array of data by making an async HTTP request to validate each row against a third party system.  This totally sorted it out.  Thank you!  (for the record, something like: `filterPromise(rows, (row) => { return axios.get(blah blah returns a Promise).then( data => { return data.passes.the.boolean.test; }) }).then( resultRows => { resolve(resultRows); })` .. (in my case I was already in an async function that has a `resolve` function that would resolve the Promise returned by my function).  Hope that helps someone :)

Comment: Edit: used `lodasync` in the end, see Keller's post below, but still, it's nice to see the algorithm laid out in all its beauty :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this...

```js
theArrayYouWantToFilter = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
  const tempArray = [];

  theArrayYouWantToFilter.filter(async (element, index) => {
    const someAsyncValue = await someAsyncFunction();

    if (someAsyncValue) {
      tempArray.push(someAsyncValue);
    }

    if (index === theArrayYouWantToFilter.length - 1) {
      resolve(tempArray);
    }
  });
});
```

Wrapped within an async function...

```js
async function filter(theArrayYouWantToFilter) {
  theArrayYouWantToFilter = await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    const tempArray = [];

    theArrayYouWantToFilter.filter(async (element, index) => {
      const someAsyncValue = await someAsyncFunction();

      if (someAsyncValue) {
        tempArray.push(someAsyncValue);
      }

      if (index === theArrayYouWantToFilter.length - 1) {
        resolve(tempArray);
      }
    });
  });

  return theArrayYouWantToFilter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A valid way to do this (but it seems too messy):

```
let arr = [1,2,3];

function filter(num) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if( num === 3 ) {
        res(num);
      } else {
        rej();
      }
    }, 1);
  });
}

async function check(num) {
  try {
    await filter(num);
    return true;
  } catch(err) {
    return false;
  }
}

(async function() {
  for( let num of arr ) {
    let res = await check(num);
    if(!res) {
      let index = arr.indexOf(num);
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})();
```

Again, seems way too messy.

Comment: FYI the `async`/`await` keywords are ES7 (Candidate) not ES6

Answer (score 0):

A variant of @DanRoss's:

```
async function filterNums(arr) {
  return await arr.reduce(async (res, val) => {
    res = await res
    if (await filter(val)) {
      res.push(val)
    }
    return res
  }, Promise.resolve([]))
}
```

Note that if (as in current case) you don't have to worry about filter() having
side effects that need to be serialized, you can also do:

```
async function filterNums(arr) {
  return await arr.reduce(async (res, val) => {
    if (await filter(val)) {
      (await res).push(val)
    }
    return res
  }, Promise.resolve([]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, and I know that my answer is similar to other already posted answers, but the function I'm going to share is ready for be dropped into any code and be used.
As usual, when you have to do complex operations on arrays, reduce is king:

```
const filterAsync = (asyncPred) => arr => 
  arr.reduce(async (acc,item) => {
    const pass = await asyncPred(item);
    if(pass) (await acc).push(item);
    return acc;
  },[]);
```

It uses modern syntax so make sure your target supports it. To be 100% correct you should use `Promise.resolve([])` as the initial value, but JS just doesn't care and this way it is way shorter.

Then you can use it like this:

```
var wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
const isOdd = x => wait(1).then(()=>x%2);
(filterAsync(isOdd)([1,2,3,4,4])).then(console.log) // => [1,3]
```

Comment: If I understand it correctly, this version checks the predicates serially, so it's likely to be slower than @GabeRogan's parallel `map()` which I think is the best (and should be the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version of @pie6k's Typescript version:

```js
async function filter<T>(arr: T[], callback: (val: T) => Promise<Boolean>) {
  const fail = Symbol()
  const result = (await Promise.all(arr.map(async item => (await callback(item)) ? item : fail))).filter(i => i !== fail)
  return result as T[] // the "fail" entries are all filtered out so this is OK
}
```

Comment: You should use a type guard instead of a type assertion here. `.filter((i): i is Awaited<T> => i !== fail);`

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way of approaching this is by processing arrays as iterables, so you can apply any number of required operations in a single iteration.

The example below uses library [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) for that:

```
import {pipe, filter, toAsync} from 'iter-ops';

const arr = [1, 2, 3]; // synchronous iterable

const i = pipe(
    toAsync(arr), // make our iterable asynchronous
    filter(async (value, index) => {
        // returns Promise<boolean>
    })
);

(async function() {
    for await (const a of i) {
        console.log(a); // print values
    }
})();
```

All operators within the library support asynchronous predicates when inside an asynchronous pipeline (why we use [toAsync](https://vitaly-t.github.io/iter-ops/functions/toAsync.html)), and you can add other operators, in the same way.

Use of `Promise.all` for this is quite inefficient, because you block the entire array from any further processing that can be done concurrently, which the above approach allows.