# ReactJS / ES6: Searching Japanese text using includes?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, cjk

So, I'm writing a client-side search and I need to look through strings of Japanese characters. I'm wondering how to do this properly?... i.e. Do I change the format of the text into `utf-8 something` and then search the `utf-8`?

Example:

All my data has `japaneseData.title` : "フェリーチェ三田"
When I type in my `search.value` as : "フェ" using `japaneseData.title.includes(search.value)` I don't get a match...

How do I do this correctly?

Okay, after further inspection, the comments were correct and `includes` was finding the substring. This is all happening inside of a `filter()` and I'm trying to return the objects that match...

After changing my code to:

```
let filteredArrayofObjects = Lists.houseLists.filter(house => house.building_name.includes(query.search));
```

I was getting back some but not all. Problem cases:

```
"アーバイルスパシエ芝浦BAY-SIDE".includes("エ芝浦"); // this evaluates to true, but does not get included in my filtered array...
```

Okay, further digging, it seems the issue is I need to wait for the filter process before returning the results... haven't yet found a solution to that just yet.

```
async filter(arr, callback) {
    return (await Promise.all(
      arr.map(async item => {
        return (await callback(item)) ? item : undefined;
      })
    )).filter(i => i !== undefined);
  }

  handleFilterLists = async (query = {}) => {
    const { Lists } = this.props;

    let searchResults = await this.filter(Lists.houseLists, async house => {
      return house.building_name.includes(query.search);

       // the final evaluation to look similar to this:
       // var newArray = homes.filter(function (el) {
       // return el.price <= 1000 &&
       // el.sqft >= 500 &&
       // el.num_of_beds >=2 &&
       // el.num_of_baths >= 2.5;
       // });

    });

    this.setState({ searchResults });
  }
```

Okay, so, I'm trying to set `state.searchResults` after the filter method has checked for matching objects in the array Lists.houseLists...

Comment: Would you post some examples of titles so it could be easier to test solutions?

Comment: `"フェリーチェ三田".includes("フェ")` returns `true` in my Chromium@Linux. Have you checked your `search.value` does not have trailing spaces or something else?

Comment: @skyboyer updated

Comment: @cnexans updated to show problem case

Comment: If includes works as expected but the array doesn't then reasonable conculsion is that you're missing something, isn't it? In code-related problems http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve is necessary.

Comment: @estus though I was initially annoyed at your condescension, after digging a bit more, it seems I need to wait for the filtering to complete before updating the search results... any ideas on the best way to do that?

Comment: There's no condescension, just a deduction. MCVE is not a fancy but a necessity, exactly because it allows to clarify the problem. It is still needed because it's unclear what's going on there - `filter` is synchronous and shouldn't be waited. A simple way to replicate the problem would be helpful - a plunk, etc.

Comment: @estus Okay, I have updated the full code I'm working on, based on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise

Comment: I see. In your case all code is synchronous, so async/await stuff is unneeded. If you use promises for a reason and your real code differs, the problem is possibly there. Also, there is no error handling.

Comment: @estus Okay, you were right, there was an underlying problem I was overlooking, my bad! Thanks for the help, I should have approached your comment with more humility...

Comment: Sure, no problems. Glad if it helped.

Comment: @estus Yeah, I fixed it, it is working now. Wish I could accept your comments as accepted answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`includes` returns true or false if the substring is detected or not. If you want the index of where the first detected substring begins, use `indexOf`.

I used your sample source and search text with `includes` and it returns true.

Edit:

I used your updated data and this still works. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMWpwe

```
const sourceText = 'アーバイルスパシエ芝浦BAY-SIDE';
const searchText = 'エ芝浦';
const lists = [
  'スパシエ',
  '芝浦BAY-SIDE',
  'エ芝浦',
  'パシエ芝浦BAY'
];

console.log(lists.filter(item => item.includes(searchText)));
// ["エ芝浦", "パシエ芝浦BAY"]
```

Comment: I have updated the question to include a test case that isn't working

Comment: @Daltron Updated with a working example. I suspect your problem lies elsewhere.