# React native - How to filter array asynchronous (async/await)

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, async-await, array-filter

I have a filter method:

```
_filterItems(items) {
  return items.filter(async item => {
    let isTrue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key');
    return isTrue;
  })
}
```

Call the method this._filterItems(myItemsAsArray) always return undefined.

How can I make it works as expected?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of [Filtering an array with a function that returns a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33355528/8031815)

Comment: Could someone give me a simple solution? I have already tried many ways on google but cannot resovle the issue :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume by `AsyncStorage.getItem('key');` you meant `AsyncStorage.getItem(item);`

```
async function run(){
    let result =  await Promise.all(items.map((item)=>AsyncStorage.getItem(item)));
  result = result.filter(Boolean); // filter all non-truthy values
  console.log('result',result);

}

run();
```

here it is https://jsfiddle.net/2juypmwL/1/

Technically, you can make it even shorter :

```
async function run(){
    let result =  (await Promise.all(items.map(AsyncStorage.getItem))).filter(Boolean);
  console.log('result',result);
}

run();
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an async function with the array `.filter` method directly, since that method expects a boolean to be returned but an async function will always return a promise. Instead, you can provide a simple wrapper for it that will allow the promises to resolve first, then uses the result of those promises as the filter condition.

Example:

```js
const items = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => i);

function asyncFilter(arr, func) {
  return Promise.all(arr.map(func)).then(boolArr => arr.filter((_, i) => boolArr[i]));
}

asyncFilter(items, async n => Boolean(n % 2)).then(result => console.log(result))
```