# Unable to use async await in array filter

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Unable to use async-await in array filter!

I tried to create array and iterate using filter to add if a response is success

```
var awardCodes = [1, 2, 3, 11];

function getPosts() {
    const response = fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/user");
    return response;
}

function test(awardCodes) {
    var arr = awardCodes.filter(checkCode);
    console.log(arr, awardCodes);
}

var checkCode = async (code) => {
    try {
        let res = await getPosts();
        if (res.status == 200) {
            console.log("true");
            return true;
        } else {
            console.log("false1");
            return false;
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("false2");
        return false;
    }
    console.log("false3");
    return false;
}

test(awardCodes);
```

I expect the output to be an empty array

Comment: You give `.filter` an `async` function, which always returns a *Promise*.

Comment: Yes, filter, map, forEach etc.  Are all calback functions that don't understand Promises.  Just use `for of` etc instead.

Comment: That `checkCode` predicate doesn't even make much sense - it takes `code` as parameter but never uses it within the body. What is the intention here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter [won't wait for your promises to resolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise) before filtering. Use `Promise.all` or `Promise.allSettled` to make your requests in parallel, once they are all done check if the codes are all valid, e.g:

```
const awardCodes = [1, 2, 3, 11];

async function filterValidCodes(awardCodes) {
  const responses = await Promise.all(
    awardCodes.map(code => fetch(`https://checkcode.com/${code}`))
  );

  return awardCodes.filter((_, i) => responses[i].status === 200);
}

(async () => {
  const validCodes = await filterValidCodes(awardCodes);
})();
```

It would be simpler and much more efficient to pass the codes as an array to the service though.

Comment: how to modify awardCodes based on each fetch call if fetch is success i want that element to be in awardCodes else it should be removed