# Filtering a list of promises inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

I found that it's not straight forward to filter a list of values of promises, so I tried the approach in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33355528/filtering-an-array-with-a-function-that-returns-a-promise) question (top answer).

The difference is, i'm using this inside `useEffect` in React.

My `results` array is empty outside of the async `getData` function:

```
// helper function
async function filter(arr, callback) {
  const fail = Symbol();
  return (
    await Promise.all(arr.map(async (item) => ((await callback(item)) ? item : fail)))
  ).filter((i) => i !== fail);
}

useEffect(() => {
      if (!stateData) {
        let results = [];

        async function getData() {
          const res = await filter(data.slice(0, 5), async (item) => {
            const boolRes = await myAsyncFunction(item);
            return boolRes;
          });
          // results has data 
          results.push(...res);
        }
        getData();
        console.log(results) // is empty, but results inside getData has data
      }
  }, []);
```

any idea how I can pull the data out of `getData` safely?

Comment: Are you looking for `Promise.allSettled`?

Comment: getData() is an async function, it does not executes immediately and your console.log(results) is called before getData completes. Try getData().then(() => console.log(results);

Comment: "*how I can pull the data out of `getData` safely?*" - you don't. Just move the `console.log` (or any `setState` that should change your component state) inside the `getData` function. You should also move the `const results` declaration inside the function, it's never useful outside of it.