# How to compare two blobs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-level2

I load two blob files in JavaScript using the code below.

I want to compare them to see if they are precisely the same.

(blob1 === blob2) is returning false, even though the reported size of each blob is 574 bytes. What am I doing wrong?

```
  getHTTPAsBlob(url, callback) {
    let cacheBust = Math.random().toString()
    url = url + '?&cachebust=' + cacheBust
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        // get binary data as a response
        let fileData = this.response;
        let contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type")
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = (e) => {
          console.log(reader.result)
          console.log(fileData)
          callback(null, {
              Body: reader.result,
              Blob: fileData,
              ContentType: contentType,
              Etag: null,
              LastModified: null,
            })
        }
        reader.readAsText(fileData)
        } else {
        callback(xhr)
      }
      }
      xhr.send();
    }
```

Comment: I think you have to read the "blob" if you want to compare its contents (using FileReader). Wouldn't it be easier to set responseType to "arraybuffer", especiallly if they are so small?

Comment: If you look at my code you'll see it uses filereader to get the text out of the blob but that is beside the point, reading should not be needed for comparing two blobs.

Comment: @DukeDugal: Why would reading not be needed to compare two blobs? How else do you want to compare them, if not by their contents?

Answer (score 1):

## You must use a FileReader to compare them

The documentation for [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) is on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/). Take a look at methods to choose what's best for your data.

A useless way of comparing two blobs is looking at their size. Although two blobs of the same size will return true no matter their content.

### Example

`new Blob([Math.random()]).size == new Blob([Math.random()]).size  // true`.

Answer (score 1):

I think "blob compare" plug-in will be help you.
It can compare blob size,type and so on.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/blob-compare

but I don't know if this plug-in is the perfect way.

Comment: In 2023, i'm using blob-compare. See my answer for another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342813/6122411

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a case of comparing two completely independent pointers that reference comparable content.  To see how this might work for simpler content, try the following in the javascript console:

`new Number(5) == new Number(5)`

Returns false.  Frustrating that 5 as an object does not equal an object whose value is 5. But at least this puts Blob into context.

I'm running into this same problem, and agree with the previous suggestion that FileReader is the only option.

Answer (score 0):

The question was asked in context of JavaScript in the browser, but in case anyone wants to compare blobs in Node.js:

```js
const areBlobsEqual = async (blob1, blob2) => {
  return !Buffer.from(await blob1.arrayBuffer()).compare(
    Buffer.from(await blob2.arrayBuffer())
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

See this answer to a similar question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342813/6122411

In short, it is to **Convert the File/Blob to ArrayBuffer using FileReader. Then perform byte-to-byte check on the buffer.** A library is recommended in that above answer.